# How to check if user have disabled sounds for notifications?

Tags: android, android-notifications

In Android 7 you can long click a notification and choose to that notifications from the belonging app should be displayed without sounds.

For Android 7 we have [`NotificationManager.areNotificationsEnabled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#areNotificationsEnabled()) to check if user have blocked the notifications for your app. **How do you check if the user have just disabled the sounds for the notifications for the app?**

**Update:**
The question still stands for Android 8/O. We have a few users who complain about not hearing any sounds and then they have disabled it without knowing it and without us having a chance to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds are enabled at IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT and upwards, so you can check like this:

```
@RequiresApi(26)
private boolean hasSoundsEnabled(String channelId) {
    NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    NotificationChannel channel = manager.getNotificationChannel(channelId);

    return channel.getImportance() >= NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
}
```